# Class autoloader in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, build, ember.js, browserify

I am looking for an autoloader, similar to how they operate in languages (e.g. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).  I merely specify the algorithm for finding the file and it's automatically loaded into the app.

My initial thinking is a build process that scans directories and builds an index file.  Is there a better way?

Comment: What server side framework are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could use a pre-made tool like [Yeoman's ember generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-ember) or [ember tools](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-tools).  They are opinionated about the project's folder structure.

Comment: I ended up using ember-tools.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution using browserify and a node.js build script, but I'm curious if anyone has a better solution:

build.js:

```
var glob = require("glob");
var fs   = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

function buildFile(directory, build_file, suffix) {
  glob(directory, function(err, files) {
    if (fs.existsSync(build_file)) {
      fs.unlinkSync(build_file);
    }
    fs.appendFileSync(build_file, 'module.exports = {');
    var controllers = {};
    files.forEach(function (file) {
      var key = path.basename(file, '.js')+suffix;
      var value = "require('"+file+"')";
      fs.appendFileSync(build_file, '\n  '+key+': '+value + ',');
    });
    fs.appendFileSync(build_file, '\n}');
  });
};

buildFile('./controllers/*.js' , './controllers.js', 'Controller');
buildFile('./routes/*.js'      , './routes.js'     , 'Route');
```

app.js:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();
App.reopen(require('./controllers.js'));
App.reopen(require('./routes.js'));
```

routes.js (example output from build.js):

```
module.exports = {
  ApplicationRoute: require('./routes/Application.js'),
  IndexRoute: require('./routes/Index.js'),
  RecoverRoute: require('./routes/Recover.js'),
  RegisterRoute: require('./routes/Register.js'),
  UsersRoute: require('./routes/Users.js'),
  UsersNewRoute: require('./routes/UsersNew.js'),
  ValidateRoute: require('./routes/Validate.js'),
}
```

I use Grunt.js to watch and rebuild automatically when changes occur.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use something like RequireJS: http://requirejs.org/

RequireJS will allow you to specify dependencies which will be loaded as needed.  You can also run the [RequireJS optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) to compile your templates and JavaScript in to one file to deploy to your production servers.

Comment: Can I specify an entire directory as a dependency?

Comment: You want to think in terms of modules... you usually can't just say "include this whole directory" as javascript tends to need to be loaded in a certain order.  So instead, you want to create a module which contains all of the files needed for a feature.  Then, elsewhere in your application you can include that module, instead of all of the individual files.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I understand that, but the point of the question is to specify those dependencies more dynamically rather than tediously managing a list.